# Simple app creation-Applescript kext load and sudo terminal command execution in a single file

Tags: terminal, command, applescript, sudo, kernel-extension

:) 
First of all I'd like to tell you that I'm not a programer (I'm musician) and I'm not very familiar with coding,but I was able to create a simple Applescript app where I execute 2 terminal commands to be able to run my FireWire Sound Card. The problem is, that I want to wrap all the commands and the kext file in a single app and after that to make it start when the system boots up. Is it possible and will I be able to do that with Applescript or Automator? If yes,can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Here are the two commands that I have to execute:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
sudo kextload ./FW_Nub/M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext
echo FireWire driver bundle loaded, NUB matched!
```

And...

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
sudo kextutil -m ./FW410/M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext
echo FireWire 410 card matched!
echo Card is ready to use!
```

Comment: For loading the kext, would it not be more sensible to simply copy it into /Library/Extensions to get it to autoload on hotplug or boot? `sudo cp -r M-AudioFireWireBeBoB.kext /Library/Extensions/`

Comment: (Same for the other kext, FWIW, except if they genuinely have the same name but are different kexts, you'll need to rename one; This shouldn't cause any issues.)

Comment: You said, "Here are the two commands that I have to execute:" but there are 7 command shown! What do you expect `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` to do? As you have the commands written `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` errors out with `dirname: illegal option -- b` and `usage: dirname path`. What does any of this have to do with AppleScript!?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answers! Actually those are not Applescript commands I executed,but the two commands for Terminal I had to execute every time when I start my computer in order to make my soundcard working. So I just recorded what I was doing with the record option in Applescript and I made one click app. The problems in this case are two...

Comment: First I had to generally disable the Sudo Password and second if I change the directory of the kext file (which is not located in /System/Library/Extentions) I guess my app will not work (I want to help other users of the same sound card to be able to start their device easier). So I want to put the kext file and the commands on one place and make it an app. Sorry if I can't explain it right,but please don't judge me to hard,because I don't understand much of coding, in fact I use MacOS since 6-7 months... :)

Comment: If you think that I'll not be able to do it, just tell me and I'll delete my post! :)
Thanks for understanding!